# BGE: How can I make a hostile animal artificial intelligence?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In the blender game engine, how do I make an animal change it's condition from walking to attacking when it sees the player?

Comment: It seems a standard enemy AI would work. What exactly do you want it to do? I might not be able to help, but it would help others to have some more information :-)

Comment: I want link to tutorial...

Comment: Something like [this?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7ebGbM85xc)

Comment: Sorry man, tutorial requests are strictly off-topic. See [how to ask](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As you see, NoviceInDisguise gave me 1 already. But I don't understand, why are htye off-topic and what exactly off-topic means in this site.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6) Being a community site, we can't be spending a lot of time/resources on tutorials, seeing as the likely-hood of another person needing *exactly* what you need is very low. If there is a certain part you are struggling with, ask about it, and we can help. Like *how can I make my enemy AI play an animation while eating my face?*

Comment: But how can I ask that if I don't know how to make enemy AI? I want to make enemy AI so I need help to make it.

Comment: Start small. Ask questions that can be answered quickly, without video, and without extensive hoo-ha to a *particular* case. I assume you can model a tiger. Next, you can animate him. Next, ask how to make him patrol a certain area looking for you while he plays a walking animation. Rather than "How to make hostile AI animal" you can ask "How to make a hostile AI animal prowl around"

Comment: THis question is asking for the last thing you listed. I will edit question, if it is not as fresh as needed...

Comment: Very good. A reopening is in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *states*. Basically this will be :

Near property *Player* > And > State *set state 2*

It will look like this.

[image]

Now on state two, you need an *Always* sensor rigged up to a *Steering* acctuator with the player being the target object.

To avoid being stuck in state 2 forever, make something to switch back when the player isn't nearby anymore.

Comment: Yes, that is near with invert selected which switches back to state 1. Thanks, this thing works!:)